# Tika server expect no body for encrypted zip

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

Tika-server docker 2.9.1.0

Imagine, we got test_archive_with_password.zip with password `123`

File size is 8,7K and

And this file has inner files

[image]

If we curl such a file to Tika-server

```
curl -T test_archive_with_password.zip -H "Accept:application/zip" -H "Password:123" http://localhost:9998/unpack > destination.zip
```

[image]

By cmd it seems like unpack successful. But result size of destination.zip is 0 bytes...

And of course no inner files inside this destination.zip